# Bind nameservers are not reaching Nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, centos7, bind9

All my Docker containers are using the same macvlan (brige) on the server.
Before bringing my Nginx up, I'm running this small script first:

```
echo "- attatching our busy0 interface to the parent via bridge;"
sudo ip link add busy0 link enp0s25 type macvlan mode bridge
echo "- giving a specific IP to our busy0 interface ending in .99;"
sudo ip addr add 192.168.50.99/24 dev busy0
echo "- bringing busy0 interface up;"
sudo ifconfig busy0 up
```

My local DNS servers are 2 vms with Centos 7 and bind9.

Setup:

- Asus router: 192.168.50.1; from here, I gave static IPs to the server host and name servers;
- Server (Ubuntu 22.04), host of the container: 192.168.50.30;
- ho.me (nginx:alpine), IP: 192.168.50.2;
- ns1.ho.me (Centos 7, bind9, Proxmox vm1), IP: 192.168.50.41;
- ns2.ho.me (Centos 7, bind9, Proxmox vm1), IP: 192.168.50.42.
- my Nginx Alpine Dockerfile:

```
# Pull latest Alpine linux image
FROM nginx:alpine
# Upgrade
RUN apk add --update && \
apk upgrade 
# Copy the Nginx config
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
# Expose the port for access
EXPOSE 80/tcp
STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
# Run the Nginx server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

- nginx, default.conf:

```
server {
        listen  80;
        listen  127.0.0.1:80;
        listen  192.168.50.2:80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name  ho.me www.ho.me;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
        location / {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        location /courses {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/courses/;
                autoindex on;
        }
        location /share {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/share/;
                autoindex on;
        }
}
```

- ns1, /etc/named.conf:

```
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/named.conf.local";
```

- ns1, /etc/named.conf.options:

```
acl trusted {
        192.168.50.0/24;
};
options {
        # IP or localhost
        listen-on port 53 { 192.168.50.41; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { trusted; };
        allow-transfer  { 192.168.50.42; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation no;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
        forwarders {

                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};
```

- ns1, /etc/named.conf.local:

```
zone "ho.me" IN {
        type master;
 # The path to your domain zone file
        file "/etc/named/ho.me.zone";
 # The IP address of the future DNS slave
        allow-transfer { 192.168.50.42; };
};
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
 # 192.168.50.0/24 subnet
        file "/etc/named/192.168.zone";
 # The IP address of the DNS slave
        allow-transfer { 192.168.50.42; };
};
```

- ns1, /etc/named/ho.me.zone

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.ho.me. root.ho.me. (
                        29
                        604800
                        86400
                        2419200
                        604800 )

; name servers – NS records
@       IN      NS      ns1.ho.me.
@       IN      NS      ns2.ho.me.

; 192.168.50.0/24 – A records 
router                  IN      A       192.168.50.1
www.ho.me.      IN      A       192.168.50.2
@                       IN      A       192.168.50.2
transmission            IN      A       192.168.50.3
jellyfin                IN      A       192.168.50.4
;
ns1                     IN      A       192.168.50.41
ns2                     IN      A       192.168.50.42
```

- ns1, /etc/named/192.168.zone

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.ho.me. root.ho.me. (
                28; Serial
                604800 ; Refresh
                86400 ; Retry
                2419200 ; Expire
                604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers – NS records
@       IN      NS      ns1.ho.me.
@       IN      NS      ns2.ho.me.

; 192.168.50.0/24 – A records
router          IN      A       192.168.50.1
www             IN      A       192.168.50.2
@               IN      A       192.168.50.2
transmission    IN      A       192.168.50.3
jellyfin        IN      A       192.168.50.4
; name server resolution
ns1             IN      A       192.168.50.41
ns2             IN      A       192.168.50.42
;chromebook.ho.me.      IN      A       192.168.50.200

; PTR records
1.50    IN      PTR     router.ho.me.           ; referring to 192.168.50.1
2.50    IN      PTR     ho.me.                  ; 192.168.50.2
3.50    IN      PTR     transmission.ho.me.     ; 192.168.50.3
4.50    IN      PTR     jellyfin.ho.me.         ; 192.168.50.4
41.50   IN      PTR     ns1.ho.me.              ; 192.168.50.41
42.50   IN      PTR     ns2.ho.me.              ; 192.168.50.42
```

- ns2, /etc/named.conf:

```
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/named.conf.local";
```

- ns2, /etc/named.conf.options:

```
acl trusted {
        192.168.50.0/24;
};
options {
        # IP or localhost
        listen-on port 53 { 192.168.50.42; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { trusted; };
        allow-transfer  { none; };
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation no;
        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
        forwarders {
                192.168.50.41;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};
```

- ns2, /etc/named.conf.local:

```
zone "ho.me" in {
        type slave;
        masterfile-format text;
        file "/etc/named/ho.me.zone";
        masters { 192.168.50.41; };
};
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type slave;
        masterfile-format text;
        file "/etc/named/192.168.zone";
        masters { 192.168.50.41; };
};
```

- ns2, /etc/named/ho.me.zone

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns2.ho.me. root.ho.me. (
                28; Serial
                604800 ; Refresh
                86400 ; Retry
                2419200 ; Expire
                604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers – NS records
        IN      NS      ns1.ho.me.
        IN      NS      ns2.ho.me.

; 192.168.50.0/24 – A records 
router                  IN      A       192.168.50.1
www                     IN      A       192.168.50.2
@                       IN      A       192.168.50.2
transmission            IN      A       192.168.50.3
jellyfin                IN      A       192.168.50.4
;
ns1                     IN      A       192.168.50.41
ns2                     IN      A       192.168.50.42
```

- ns2, /etc/named/192.168.zone

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns2.ho.me. root.ho.me. (
                26; Serial
                604800 ; Refresh
                86400 ; Retry
                2419200 ; Expire
                604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers – NS records
@       IN      NS      ns1.ho.me.
@       IN      NS      ns2.ho.me.

; 192.168.50.0/24 – A records
router          IN      A       192.168.50.1
ho              IN      A       192.168.50.2
transmission    IN      A       192.168.50.3
jellyfin        IN      A       192.168.50.4
; name server resolution
ns1             IN      A       192.168.50.41
ns2             IN      A       192.168.50.42
;chromebook     IN      A       192.168.50.200

; PTR records
1.50    IN      PTR     router.ho.me.           ; referring to 192.168.50.1
2.50    IN      PTR     ho.me.                  ; 192.168.50.2
3.50    IN      PTR     transmission.ho.me.     ; 192.168.50.3
4.50    IN      PTR     jellyfin.ho.me.         ; 192.168.50.4
41.50   IN      PTR     ns1.ho.me.              ; 192.168.50.41
42.50   IN      PTR     ns2.ho.me.              ; 192.168.50.42
```

- I entered the Nginx container and ran *nginx -t* and the output was successful;
- on ns1, ns2, I ran *named-checkconf* and *named-checkzone* and had no issue;
- on ns1 and ns2: *tail -f /var/log/messages* doesn't say anything special, all zones ok;

```
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: automatic empty zone: EMPTY.AS112.ARPA
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: automatic empty zone: HOME.ARPA
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: none:104: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 3410MB (out of 3789MB)
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: configuring command channel from '/etc/rndc.key'
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: managed-keys-zone: journal file is out of date: removing journal file
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 22
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 28
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone ho.me/IN: loaded serial 29
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: all zones loaded
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: running
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 systemd: Started Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone ho.me/IN: sending notifies (serial 29)
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 28)
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1 named[25522]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . acceptance timer complete: key now trusted
```

- ns1, ns2: *systemctl status named.service*, again, nothing special:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-03-31 18:27:12 CEST; 52s ago
  Process: 25505 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/rndc stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25520 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25518 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25522 (named)
    Tasks: 4
   CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
           └─25522 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf -4

Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: zone ho.me/IN: loaded serial 29
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: all zones loaded
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: running
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me systemd[1]: Started Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: zone ho.me/IN: sending notifies (serial 29)
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 28)
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . acceptance timer complete: key now trusted
Mar 31 18:27:12 ns1.ho.me named[25522]: resolver priming query complete
```

- after configuring the name servers, I've setup the router to advertise them first and then his own; and I've tested this - I'm connecting from the work laptop to the router network, leaving all settings default to DHCP on this work laptop and when I'm looking to see what IPs it got from the network, I can see 3 DNSs in this order: .41, .42 and .1; I can't ping my local ho.me, I'm receiving the IP from the actual ho.me parked domain out there;
- now, since the router is advertising first my name servers and then its own, the server host (.30) of the Nginx container (.2), should be using my own name servers but it's not, because I can't ping ho.me from here - I'm receiving the IP of the actual parked domain of ho.me;
- in the router (.1), I've then went and manually assigned ns1 to my server host (.30); now, I can ping ho.me and the rest of those DNS host records (jellyfin.ho.me, transmission.ho.me, etc.) and yet, still, I can't reach http://ho.me or [www.ho.me](http://www.ho.me) in my browser;
- again, in the router (.1), I then went ahead and assigned the Nginx container itself, my ns1; nothing.

I'm not sure what am I missing out.